# Broken Indicators in 12.10

Tags: indicator, 12.10

Several of the indicators don't work for me in Ubuntu 12.10.  Specifically, indicator-sensors and the Skype indicator (I also used the ubuntuone indicator, but that hasn't come out yet for 12.10).

Indicators that do work include: sound, network, time, system, battery, empathy, indicator-multiload, and dropbox.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could try the official indicator-sync instead of ubuntuone indicator :)

Comment: Ooh,  I didn't realize that indicator-sync existed.  I tried installing it (sudo apt-get install indicator-sync), but after that, I couldn't figure out how to run it.  It didn't appear in the menu, startup applications, or as a binary that I could run.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Might be a bug, I installed it, restarted unity and it just popped up. It is brand new, and probably not ready for primetime (that's why it isn't installed by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the developer of the indicator sensor, there is no Quantal port for it yet.

[indicator sensor ppa](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors)

The ubuntuone indicator has no quantal port either.

[ubuntuone indicator](https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras)

so I guess this is the case for all your missing/broken indicators.

Answer (score 0):

It seems now it's working. I installed indicator-sensors through this same ppa on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal right now, and it worked like a charm, just like it was on Precise.

I just had to go to [Indicator Sensors' PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors), download .deb file for Precise manually, and then install it by opening the file on Nautilus File Explorer. You can download indicator-sensors' deb file for Precise from [here](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors/+files/indicator-sensors_0.2-1_i386.deb).

But that's the solution that worked for me a few weeks ago. Now there's a Quantal version of indicator-sensors on this PPA, and now you can simply install it by adding this PPA to your system.